using a struct with element name new in c++
I want to use the XColormapEvent structure in c++.
It is defined as
typedef struct {
int type;
unsigned long serial;
Bool send_event;
Display *display;
Window window;
Colormap colormap;
Bool new;
int state;
} XColormapEvent;


As you can see, there is an element with the name new.
Can it be accessed with c++?
Simple example:
struct Y
{
        int new;
};

int main()
{
        Y y;
        y.new=5;  // expected unqualified-id before »new« 
}


No that structure is not compatible with C++. new is a keyword which can't be used for anything else.

C++ keywords  "...This is a list of reserved keywords in C++. Since they are used by the language, these keywords are not available for re-definition or overloading..."

@RichardCritten They should update that a little since new can be overloaded

Instead of typedef struct { ... } XColormapEvent; you should write struct XColormapEvent { ... }; They mean the same thing. Then, you create an object like this: XColormapEvent e;, and you can access its members with the dot operator: e.type = 1;

@NathanOliver good point the current draft [lex.key] misses out the "overloading" part. Good catch.

Did the author of the library claim to support C++?  If not, then nothing forces the authors from changing their header to something compatible with C++.

"Can it be accessed with c++?"  Yes.  Write C code that accesses the member, without any C++ keywords in the interface.  Compile the code with a C compiler.  Link it with your C++ code.

You should not have any problems with #include <X11/Xlib> because the struct is defined there
typedef struct {
    int type;
    unsigned long serial;   /* # of last request processed by server */
    Bool send_event;    /* true if this came from a SendEvent request */
    Display *display;   /* Display the event was read from */
    Window window;
    Colormap colormap;  /* COLORMAP or None */
#if defined(__cplusplus) || defined(c_plusplus)
    Bool c_new;     /* C++ */
#else
    Bool new;
#endif
    int state;      /* ColormapInstalled, ColormapUninstalled */
} XColormapEvent;

although all XLib manuals do not show that Bool c_new.

You cannot use new in a c++ compiler for a member variable name, but you can

Use a Modified header with different naming, the C ABI doesn't care about member names.
use the preprocessor.

#define new new_mem
#include "troublesome_header.h"
#undef new

This is not standard C++ and UB and all but it works on all compilers.
Edit: There is nothing wrong in this answer, it is only downvoted because it won't work on the hypothetical compiler that will be written in a 100 years.

Care must be taken that troublesome_header.h doesn't use the new identifier anywhere else, directly or indirectly in another included header. While I can't think of a specific case where it should use the new keyword, for example C standard library headers may still contain C++-specific code.

And if I am not mistaken, I do remember some weird case where MSVC depends on specific naming of members, although I am not sure whether that was in the ABI.

@user17732522 at least the C ABI doesn't care about member naming.

Downvotes reason: bitter truth , likely because it won't work on hypothetical compilers.
